# Cannot parse xml file in jenkins pipeline

Tags: xml, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have simple xml file, that I need to parse in pipeline.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

<AS Name="123">
    <Config Name="Configuration1">
        <Servers>
            <Server Name="server1"/>
            <Server Name="server2"/>
            <Server Name="server3"/>
            <Server Name="server4"/>
         </Servers>
    </Config>
</AS>
```

I need to extract values of all servers' names into variable. 
So I used code below but get only "unclassified field java.lang.string Config" exception

```
deleteDir()
stage("upload") {
    def inputFile = input message: 'Upload file', parameters: [file(name: 'parameters.xml')]
    new hudson.FilePath(new File("$workspace/parameters.xml")).copyFrom(inputFile)
    inputFile.delete()
}

stage ("parse")
{
    def xml = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/parameters.xml"
    def config = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)



    config.Config.Servers.Server.each{
        println it.@Name
    }

}
```

XMLSlurper didn't help too. 
What am I doing wrong?

UPD: rewrite pipeline using noncps but it didn't give the result

```
node
{

    deleteDir()
    stage("upload") {
        def inputFile = input message: 'Upload file', parameters: [file(name: 'parameters.xml')]
        new hudson.FilePath(new File("$workspace/parameters.xml")).copyFrom(inputFile)
        inputFile.delete()
     }

    stage("checkout") {
        echo fileExists('parameters.xml').toString()
    }

    stage ("parse")
    {

        def xml = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/parameters.xml"

        println servers(xml)
    }
}

@NonCPS
def servers(xmlfile) {
    def serv = [:]
    def config = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlfile)
    config.Config.Servers.Server.each{
    serv.add(it.@name)
    }
    return serv
}
```

Error ouput now is:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified field groovy.util.Node Config
```

Comment: Trying that on plain groovy complains, that it's supposed to be `standalone="yes"` (not `true`).  Also that `def` before the `config.Config.each` looks wrong.

Comment: And should be config.Config.Servers.each...

Comment: @daggett `Config.Servers.Server.each ...` surely? 

Comment: @cfrick there was no def in original code.

Comment: @tim_yates, right )))

Comment: maybe new XmlParser().parse(...) for file, not new XmlParser().parseText()?

Answer (score 3):

the following code

```groovy
def xml = '''
<AS Name="123">
    <Config Name="Configuration1">
        <Servers>
            <Server Name="server1"/>
            <Server Name="server2"/>
            <Server Name="server3"/>
            <Server Name="server4"/>
         </Servers>
    </Config>
</AS>
'''

def config = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

config.Config.Servers.Server.each{
    println it.@Name
}
```

prints

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
```

---

**for jenkins pipeline**

assume you have this the **parameters.xml**

note that in the question you have wrong xml: The standalone document declaration value must be "yes" or "no", not "true"

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<AS Name="123">
    <Config Name="Configuration1">
        <Servers>
            <Server Name="server1"/>
            <Server Name="server2"/>
            <Server Name="server3"/>
            <Server Name="server4"/>
         </Servers>
    </Config>
</AS>
```

the following pipeline prints server names:

```groovy
@NonCPS
def servers(xml) {
    new XmlParser().parseText(xml).Config.Servers.Server.collect{it.@Name}
}

node{
    def xml = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/parameters.xml"
    println servers(xml)
}
```

Comment: doesn't work in my case. "unclassified field java.lang.string Config" exception

Comment: This is a runnable code. How you execute this code? What is your environment? Could you provide full stacktrace?

Comment: I'm running this in jenkins pipeline. Stacktrace is here https://pastebin.com/zjqanY5j

Comment: For Jenkins pipeline script  you have to use @NonCPS function I think..

Comment: @NonCPS didn't help.

Comment: @PavelPolushin, updated the answer with working pipeline code

Comment: still doesn't work in my environment. Error is "org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified field groovy.util.Node Config". I got the same error earlier today (see updated question).

Comment: Found bug that describes my situation. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37398. But I don't understand what did Daniel Sobral mean when he said to " use map syntax instead of property syntax"

Comment: @PavelPolushin, my code works fine in jenkins pipeline

Comment: which version of Jenkins do you use?

Comment: Jenkins ver. 2.46.3

Comment: @daggett do I need a plugin for this? We are using 2.122 at work and I can't add an instance of XMLParser, it returns the error `unable to resolve class XMLParser`

Comment: No. XmlParser is a part of groovy. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html

Comment: And it's XmlParser not XMLParser

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37398 try to use map syntax instead of property syntax.

```
it['Name']
```

instead of ...

```
it.@Name
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem is bug of the script-security plugin.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37398